# Set Neo4j Uniqueness to NODE_PATH with Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

In order to prevent my path from including the same node more than once, I'm looking to be able to set the uniqueness to NODE_PATH either using the .Net Neo4jClient or at the database level in one of the database config files (which, last I heard, wasn't possible).

If this can be done, I'm almost certain it will solve this problem as well:

[Cypher Query in Neo4j Returns 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330864/cypher-query-in-neo4j-returns-undefined)

Thanks for any help!

Brent

Comment: i'm afraid you question is not completely understandable. could you please provide at least a part of your query you are using now, and the goal you want to have at the end of the query?

Comment: Uniqueness as in the traversal framework (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html#_uniqueness) is not yet exposed in Cypher. It's in the plans though.

Comment: @PeterNeubauer (as well as ulkas), thanks for the response. Yeah, that's exactly what I was talking about. My graph is a flight network so you can imagine how many paths there are to any particular node (airport). Currently I'm running out of memory, but even if I gave the machine more, with all the repeating nodes in the paths, the traversal would take way too long. If I understand correctly, maybe I can use the REST API to set the uniqueness and then get my data that way. Any idea how soon cypher might support this? Thanks again for being such a great resource here!

Answer (score 0):

Brent,

You could use Cypher's `CREATE UNIQUE` clause to create the relationship:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.M05/query-create-unique.html#create-unique-create-relationship-if-it-is-missing

If it already exists, it won't do anything.

-- Tatham

Comment: Did this work? If so, can you accept the answer? If not, can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think CREATE UNIQUE will just take your query, match what it can and then create any new relationship that your query specifies that isn't in your graph. For example, if I wanted to find all flights from A --> B, but no flights went from A --> B, then the graph would be modified and there would now be a flight from A --> B, which would be bad (since no such flight exists in reality).

Comment: Ah. I completely misread the question. You're just trying to do a query.